# C - emulate 'mutable' from C++

Tags: c, constants, mutable

I have a C structure like this:

```
struct my_struct {
   int i;
   double d;
   struct expensive_type * t;
};
```

An instance of this structure is created and initialized as:

```
struct my_struct * my_new( int i , double d) 
{
    struct my_struct * s = malloc( sizeof * s);
    s->i = i;
    s->d = d;
    s->t = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

Calculating the `struct expensive_type * t` member is quite expensive, and might not be needed - it is therefor just initialized to `NULL` - and later calculated on demand:

```
const struct expensive_type * my_get_expensive( const struct my_struct * s) 
{
    if (!s->t)
       s->t = my_expensive_alloc( s->i , s->d );
    return s->t;  
 }
```

In C++ I would have used `mutable` on the `struct expensive_type *`member, is it possible to achieve something similar in C, i.e. casting away the const locally:

```
{
    struct my_struct * mutable_s = (struct my_struct*) s;
    mutable_s->t = ...;
```

}

Or is removing `const` in the signature my only standard-compliant alternative?

Comment: There is no `mutable` or anything close to it in C.

Comment: Yes, need to remove `const` or suffer UB.  Nice post though.  A good answer would cite the C spec.

Comment: Why does code need the `const` in `my_get_expensive( const struct my_struct * s)`?  Perhaps that goal can be satisfied another way?

Comment: This would be an abuse of `mutable` in C++ and is not what that keyword is for.

Comment: @chux No, a good answer does not need to quote the spec. That's just nonsense. Especially for a question asking about something that's not even part of the C language...

Comment: @chux: Code does not *need* const in the `my_get_expensive( )` - however I would like to have `const` there to signal that calling the `my_get_expensive( )` does not induce observable changes in the `struct my_struct` instance.

Comment: @nwp Caching an expensive computation is one of the canonical uses of `mutable`, imho.

Comment: @rubenvb A good answer would quote the spec as to why this is not possible in C, rather than relying on vehement assertion.

Comment: But calling `my_get_expensive()` *does* induce observable changes in the `struct my_struct` instance under some circumstances, @user422005.  That's exactly why the referent of the pointer must not be `const`.

Comment: Code could use `struct expensive_type **t;` and right away allocate a pointer and assign that to `NULL`,  Then the expensive allocation could update that.  Yet that is a kludge.  I agree with [@JohnBollinger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880367/c-emulate-mutable-from-c?noredirect=1#comment74796370_43880367)

Comment: How about just not using `const` for things that are supposed to change ....

Comment: @Alan Again, how can one quote the spec (with it actually contributing to supporting the answer) if the spec contains nothing related to the subject? I could quote the C++ spec to give a completely wrong answer to this question (if it were hypothetically a C++ question) by leaving out everything about mutable. Does that make it a good answer? No. Same here. Quoting the spec doesn't make an answer good. Stack Overflow is not about who can quote the spec the most or the best. Quite the contrary. It is about people sharing their knowledge  and experience with others.

Comment: @rubenvb "if the spec contains nothing related to the subject?" is not true for this post.  OP wants to emulate C++ `mutable` in C which allows various degrees of freedom on how to achieve that goal.  I can see as possible  - although it still lacks OP goal clarity.  Suggest [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) rather than ["just nonsense"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880367/c-emulate-mutable-from-c/43880875?noredirect=1#comment74795912_43880367) to encourage sharing knowledge/experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could(1)* restructure your code and add a layer of indirection:

```
struct expensive; // Forward declaration, ignore
// One could also use a struct expensive * (a pointer) instead
// of this structure. IMO giving it a name is the better option.
struct expensive_handle {
  struct expensive * target;
};

// Store the simple data members as usual, store a pointer to a
// handle (pointer) to the expensive ones
struct my_struct {
  int simple;
  struct expensive_handle * handle;
};

struct expensive {
  int content; // whatever
};
```

Creating a `my_struct` must create the additional pointer/handle used for the indirection:

```
struct my_struct * new() {
  struct my_struct * data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
  // Error handling please
  // Set simple data members
  data->handle = malloc(sizeof(*(data->handle)));
  // Error handling please
  data->handle->target = NULL;
  return data;
}
```

The `target` member (which will point to the expensive data once it is computed) is set to `NULL` initially.

Accessing (and thus possibly lazy computation of) the expensive data members is then possible even with a `const` qualified `my_struct`, because no data member of that `my_struct` is changed:

```
int get_expensive(struct my_struct const * ptr) {
  if (ptr->handle->target == NULL) {
    ptr->handle->target = malloc(sizeof(struct expensive));
    // Error handling please
    puts("A hell of a computation just happened!");
    ptr->handle->target->content = 42; // WOO
  }
  return ptr->handle->target->content;
}
```

The only thing that changes is the data member of `*(ptr->handle)`, a `struct expensive_handle`. Which is not const qualified (only the pointer to it named `handle` is).

Test ([Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/wDxYtW)):

```
int main(void) {
  struct my_struct * p = new();
  printf("%d\n", get_expensive(p));
  printf("%d\n", get_expensive(p));
}
```

---

(1) Whether this is reasonable or a complete waste of resources (both programmer and computation) cannot be decided from your dummy example, though.

Comment: Dear down voter, please explain what parts of my answer should be improved.

Comment: Thank you - the indirection is certainly worth it in my (real ...) case!